# Is it possible to change colour with glColor3f without going out of Matrix in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to write something in HUD, and I want to use two colour alternately for words. I can't do it with many Matrixes (I mean write in many seperate glPushMatrix and glPopMatrix) because I want to save my text positon which I initiate with glRasterPos2f. I mean I can't move the position of text correctly without counting how width each letter in showed already text was because I think is a little sticky. So I want to stay in one Matrix and simply change the colour when I find a space.

EDIT
Ok, so for example if I wish to write first word in red and the others in green:

```
glPushMatrix();
    glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
    glRasterPos2f(10, 10);
    void * font = GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18;
    string label = "first second";
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < label.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = label[i];
        if (c == ' ')
        {
            i++;
            break;
        }
        glutBitmapCharacter(font, c);
    }
    glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
    for (; i < label.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = label[i];
        glutBitmapCharacter(font, c);
    }
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: Did you try it? The matrix stack and the color uniforms have no reason to interfere with each other.

Comment: @Quentin when I use glColor3f two times with different colours in one Matrix stack, my label has always the colour of first.

Comment: Please post the code that doesn't work, it will help a lot more than a description of it.

Answer (score 3):

`glutBitmapCharacter` draws the character by a call to `glBitmap`, which in turn uses the `GL_CURRENT_RASTER_COLOR`. The later is set by calls to `glRasterPos` and `glWindowPos` to the `GL_CURRENT_COLOR` at the time of the call. `glColor` updates only the `GL_CURRENT_COLOR`:

```
glColor3f(1,0,0);
glRasterPos(...); // GL_CURRENT_RASTER_COLOR = 1,0,0
glBitmap(...); // draws in red
glColor3f(0,1,0);
glBitmap(...); // still draws in red
glRasterPos(...); // GL_CURRENT_RASTER_COLOR = 0,1,0
glBitmap(...); // now draws in green
```

So the only solution is to call to `glRasterPos/glWindowPos` between the words to pick up the updated color. To accomplish that you can retrieve the `GL_CURRENT_RASTER_POSITION` as follows:

```
// ... draw first word ...

float pos[4] = {};
glGetFloatv(GL_CURRENT_RASTER_POSITION, pos);
glColor3f(0,1,0);
glWindowPos3fv(pos);

// ... draw second word ...
```

**HOWEVER**, I highly recommend to scrap all you do and switch to modern OpenGL.